# Some Query About Associative Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a question about associative arrays in PHP.

I have following associative array Where "data" is the key of that array.

```
$_SESSION['data'] = 1;
```

Now, I want to declare "data" as a variable. Like this-

```
 $data=id;

 $_SESSION['$data'] = 1;
  
 echo $_SESSION['id'];
```

Is it even possible to do that ??
Or, I'm doing it in the wrong way ??

Any Help Would Be Appreciated.
Thank u.

Comment: To set an associative key with a variable try:
`$_SESSION[$data] = 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All is okay, just use variable **without** qoutes:

```
$data = 'id';
// no quotes here
$_SESSION[$data] = 1;
echo $_SESSION['id'];
```

Comment: @Risfat putting `'$data'` with the single quotes makes it literal (you're trying to find `$data` index inside the session array, when in fact, you want the value of `$data` to be used in the index), thus the undefined index, so just remove it

Comment: @Kevin Thanks...For your interest. One more thing can I use integer data as key...of associative array ?? Like $data = 205;

Comment: @Risfat yes quite possible. in some instances you case use that integer as key that signifies as an ID in your system. it makes it easy to search in your array

Comment: @Risfat Sure, you can use integer value as index for an element of an associative array.